# Url Generation using Django

Tags: django

I need to generate a url:  /this-is-a-stub/1

Now, I don't need the 'this-is-a-stub', but I do need the '1'

How can I generate the url in my urls.py file?

I have the following:

```
url(r'^(?P<stub>[\w-]+)/(?P<id>[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,36})/$', 'myapp.views.index', 'name')
```

However, stub will need to be passed into my view.

One thing I forgot to mention:  I want to generate this using {% url 'name' stub='stub-123', id=3 %}

Comment: So. What's the problem, Paul? Everything seems fine.

Comment: If I pass "stub" into {% url ... %}, then when I call def index, I would have to pass in stub as well.  Can I just do def index(id) rather than def(stub,id)

Comment: You might hide annoing parameter under kwargs 

def index(request, id, **kwargs). 


If you still need reverse(or url tag) to work with both parameters you can't remove "stub" parameter from regex. So you'll have to leave it. If you have to leave it then you cannot get rid of it in arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need it, don't wrap it in capturing parentheses.

```
r'^[\w-]+/(?P<id>[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,36})/$'
```